# electrostatic seperator build questions

Tags: mechanical, static

I am building an electrostatic seperator for plant material. the two materials I am trying to seperate have a negative charge but one responds a lot more to positve charges so I feel there will still be sufficient separation. I have the general plan for it done, I just had a few questions in regard to the rectifier, and if anybody had any input with the other aspects it would also be greatly apreciated. So now let me get into the plan. I attached a diagram to give you all an idea of what i am talking about. I plan on running a 220V cord to a junction box. From there i will have three connections, one to each motor and then one to the rectifier.Then from the rectifier it will run to the positive electrode. Attached to the motors will be the electrodes, the negative charge rotating clockwise and the positive rotating counter-clockwise. Each electrode is going to be made of aluminum. the negative having a diameter of 6 inches and the positive a diameter of 12 inches. Each also will have a depth of 12 inches. I feel this is the max size to go with still keeping a sufficient charge on the positive electrode. Then the negative will be grounded to the steel frame. So to my questions, I was thinking of using a 35A 400V bridge rectifier and was wondering if that would be the appropriate one. Also would it be fine to run just a positive from the junction box to the rectifier then the the electrode without a ground on that side? the only ground for the electrodes would be the one on the negative charge side. If i do need one between the rectifier and positive electrode, what would be the best way of placing it there? Also do you all feel aluminum would be the best material to use for the electrodes? Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: diagram]

Comment: For electrostatic separation you will likely need a much higher voltage then just rectified 220VAC.  Possible in the range of 10KV DC or more.  For safety sake look into buying a commercially made high voltage supply with current limiting and other safety controls built in.

Comment: @Nedd i am just looking to create a 2-4 inch material separation over a 2-2.5 ft drop. i feel that the static energy generated from a 220v is sufficient as the material particles are sub .01 of a gram.

Answer (score 1):

At least in principle, aluminum is not a good electrode material. The reason is that when exposed to air, aluminum quickly (that is, almost instantaneously) forms an aluminum oxide layer, and alumina is an excellent insulator. As a result, your particles, unless they pierce the oxide, will not pick up a charge.

More importantly, I'm dubious about using electrostatic separation with plant material. As a rough estimate, I'd expect the differential sensitivity to be explained by moisture content, in which case a simple density separation will be easier and less dangerous. I bring up danger, because if your plant material produces organic dust during the process you run the risk of dust explosions and fires.

Comment: so stainless steel would be a better option for the electrodes, I just selected aluminum due to it being a better conductor but i didnt take the oxidation into factor. since i wont be using enough voltage to create a corona discharge, i feel the combustion risk is low. i am just looking to create a 2-4 inch material separation over a 2-2.5 ft drop. i feel that static energy generated from a 220v is sufficient as the material particles are sub .01 of a gram.

Comment: Fine particles of dry organic materials are ALWAYS a problem when it comes to fire/explosion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg7mLSG-Yws. And why, exactly, do you think that 220 will give you enough force? Experiments? Calculations?

Comment: i have done some simple household experiments using rubber, latex, and plastics and the static from them creates enough of a pull